# React -- conditional render not clear input value

Tags: reactjs, input, conditional-rendering

My code is

```
class Com extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {is_clicked: false};
    }

    render() {
        let sub_com1 = () => {
            return (
                <div>Input1:<input/></div>
            );
        };
        let sub_com2 = () => {
            return (
                <div>Input2:<input/></div>
            );
        };
        return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.state.is_clicked ? sub_com1() : sub_com2()}
            </div>
            <button onClick={()=>{
                               let is_clicked=this.state.is_clicked;
                               this.setState({is_clicked: !is_clicked});
                            }}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and the live display: [codepen](https://codepen.io/Evian-Zhang/pen/bGNmLeN?editable=true&editors=001).

In this code, I use conditional rendering in `Com`'s render method.

## What I expect

Each time I click the button, the input area should be cleared since it is rendered to another component

## What I met

Each time I click the button, the "input1" or "input2" label has changed, but the input area is not cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue you have to add `key` attributes to your input elements, change the code be like this and it will work:

```
class Com extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {is_clicked: false};
    }

    render() {
        let sub_com1 = () => {
            return (
                <div>Input1:<input key={1} id='A' /></div>
            );
        };
        let sub_com2 = () => {
            return (
                <div>Input2:<input key={2} id='b' /></div>
            );
        };
        return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.state.is_clicked ? sub_com1() : sub_com2()}
            </div>
            <button onClick={()=>{
                               let is_clicked=this.state.is_clicked;
                               this.setState({is_clicked: !is_clicked});
                            }}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Com/>,
  mountNode,
);
```

The following article discuss it in more depth and why its important to have key attribute for elements:

full article: [keys-in-children-components-are-important](https://www.jstips.co/en/react/keys-in-children-components-are-important/)

> Key is not really about performance, it’s more about identity (which
>   in turn leads to better performance). Randomly assigned and changing
>   values do not form an identity Paul O’Shannessy